# Função não funciona dentro da classe [Laravel]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, php-7

Estou tentando chamar uma função dentro de outra em um dos controllers do meu projeto Laravel, porém quando a chama a pagina fica toda em branco e não apresenta nenhum erro.

```
public function index()
    {
      $departamentos = Departamento::all();
      $clientes = Cliente::all()->sortByDesc("id");
      $lastCliente = Cliente::all()->sortByDesc("id")->first();
      return view('clientes', compact('clientes','departamentos','lastCliente'));
    }


public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $cliente = new Cliente();
        $cliente->nome = $request->input('nomeCliente');
        $cliente->idade = $request->input('idadeCliente');
        $cliente->departamento_id = $request->input('idDepartamento');
        $cliente->descricao = $request->input('descricaoCliente');
        $cliente->save();
        $this->index(); <-----------
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu deves retornar um redirect.

```
return redirect()->route('index.route...');
```

Redireciona pra rota index... É errado simplesmente chamar o método index dentro do store (pois este é um post), tu deve **redirecionar** pro método index.